# Get failed service name inside Consul watch handler

Tags: consul, consul-health-check

I'm using Consul to monitor services health status. I use Consul `watch` command to fire a handler when some service is failed. Currently I'm using this command:

`consul watch -type=checks -state=passing /home/consul/health.sh`

This works, however I'd like to know inside `health.sh` the name of the failed service, so I could send a proper alert message containing failed service name. How can I get failed service name there?

Answer (score 1):

Your script could get all the required information by reading from `stdin`. Information will be sent as JSON. You can easily examine those events by simply adding `cat - | jq .` into your handler.

Answer (score 0):

The check information outputted by `consul watch -type=check` contains a `ServiceName` field that contains the name of the service the check is associated with.

```json
[
  {
    "Node": "foobar",
    "CheckID": "service:redis",
    "Name": "Service 'redis' check",
    "Status": "passing",
    "Notes": "",
    "Output": "",
    "ServiceID": "redis",
    "ServiceName": "redis"
  }
]
```

(See https://www.consul.io/docs/dynamic-app-config/watches#checks for official docs.)

Checks associated with services should have values in both the `ServiceID` and `ServiceName` fields. These fields will be empty for node level checks.

The following command watches changes in health checks, and outputs the name of a service when its check transitions to a state other than "passing" (i.e., warning or critical).

```sh
$ consul watch -type=checks -state=passing "jq --raw-output '.[] | select(.ServiceName!=\"\" and .Status!=\"passing\") | .ServiceName'"
```